# Error installing h5py using pip

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, hdf5, h5py

Error installing  h5py using pip

Environment:- spark service IBM bluemix
!pip install --user h5py fails with error gcc failed.

I even tried to download the package and then run !python setup.py install

Comment: h5py is not a standalone library. It requires native  HDF5 libs which cannot be installed by pip.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example notebook](https://github.com/joshisa/bluemix-hdf5/blob/master/hdf5.ipynb) that illustrates how to:

1. Grab a copy of the native HDF5 lib source and extract
2. Configure, Make and Install the native HDF5 libs
3. Successfully complete the install of h5py onto a notebook within the Bluemix Spark service.
4. Executes some of the h5py quick start guide sample code.

Hope this helps.